# Calendar on Yosemite

Tags: macos

I updated to Maverick and found that CALENDAR no longer could integrate "To Do" Items with events. Will Yosemite have this needed capabiity?

Answer (score 1):

The "To Do" list on Mavericks and Yosemite is now separate app and it is called Reminders.

You will find it in your Applications folders.